# how to Display this json like chartjs chart model

Tags: angular, typescript, chartjs-2.6.0

i am new to chartjs i want charts using chartjs here i have json so i want to display like this that is [Sample Image is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBcVz.png)  so please help me
and json array is

```
[
      {
        "ChartGroupName": "Group-A",
        "Apple": 45,
        "Banana": 37,
        "Kiwi_fruit": 60,
        "Blueberry": 70,
        "Orange": 46,
        "Grape_Fruit": 33
      },
      {
        "ChartGroupName": "Group-B",
        "Apple": 50,
        "Banana": 35,
        "Kiwi_fruit": 70,
        "Blueberry": 65,
        "Orange": 40,
        "Grape_Fruit": 53
      },
      {
        "ChartGroupName": "Group-C",
        "Apple": 55,
        "Banana": 39,
        "Kiwi_fruit": 80,
        "Blueberry": 75,
        "Orange": 52,
        "Grape_Fruit": 73
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided your `JSON` data is present in an array named `data`, you could generate `labels` and `datasets` as follows:

```
const labels = Object.keys(data[0]).slice(1).map(l => l.replace('_', ' '));
const datasets = data.map((o, i) => ({
    label: o[0],
    data: Object.values(o).slice(1),
    backgroundColor: colors[i]
  })
);
```

Please take a look at below runnable code snippet that illustrates how it works.

```js
const data = [
  {
    "ChartGroupName": "Group-A",
    "Apple": 45,
    "Banana": 37,
    "Kiwi_fruit": 60,
    "Blueberry": 70,
    "Orange": 46,
    "Grape_Fruit": 33
  },
  {
    "ChartGroupName": "Group-B",
    "Apple": 50,
    "Banana": 35,
    "Kiwi_fruit": 70,
    "Blueberry": 65,
    "Orange": 40,
    "Grape_Fruit": 53
  },
  {
    "ChartGroupName": "Group-C",
    "Apple": 55,
    "Banana": 39,
    "Kiwi_fruit": 80,
    "Blueberry": 75,
    "Orange": 52,
    "Grape_Fruit": 73
  }
];
const colors = ['orange', 'yellow', 'lightblue']

const labels = Object.keys(data[0]).slice(1).map(l => l.replace('_', ' '));
const datasets = data.map((o, i) => ({
    label: o['ChartGroupName'],
    data: Object.values(o).slice(1),
    backgroundColor: colors[i]
  })
);

new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: datasets
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }],
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Comment: you hard coded here based on Json but i want dynamically from service

Comment: Please take a look at my updated answer that now also shows how the chart config can be generated out of given JSON data.

Comment: thank you so much for your help @uminder its working well. and i want get random colors dynamical . really your amazing . i hope you given solution for this also